# How to monitor iframe from parent website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website called A i want to include another website called B into A using iframe. Website B is an e-shopping site. I want to monitor all the pages of B through A. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor all the pages of B through A"? If you own both websites, why not just add an analytics script in the e-commerce iframe document?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the domains, protocols and ports of sites A and B, you are quite likely to face issues related to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

It will also depend on what you mean by *I want to monitor all the pages of B through A*.

If you own both sites A and B and if they are on different domains, you can implement [cross-document messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging), using the HTML5 postMessage feature.

A nice wrapper for postMessage can be found [here](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/). It uses jQuery if possible, and falls back to location hash on IE7.

Comment: i want to count how many clicks happen in Website B's Home page like other page also

Comment: and also want to monitor how many shopping done through Website A

Comment: Please include all these comments in your question, so that information is not scattered all over the place. That way people will have an easier time giving you useful answers.

Comment: i need time to understand the document you have given thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can only make a list of websites that are loaded from the internal iframe when domains are different.

If you are using jQuery:

```
<script>
var webList=[];
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#b").load(function(){
        webList.push($(this).attr("src"));
    });
})
</script>
<iframe id="b"></iframe>
```